# How to display Live Earthquake Data using Python

Tags: python, live, real-time-data

I am trying to extract data from this https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php in real-time so I can visualize this on a real-time dashboard.

On your right side you can see

Past 30 Days
Updated every minute.
All earthquake (this is the dataset)

I would like to extract this an update live. I have downloaded the data locally, and I have read multiple articles but i dont where I have to go. Should I webscrape the URl link maybe?

Comment: Did you check the API documentation? If you follow links, there seems to be a decent amount of information on how to set up a feed. Start here: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/

Comment: What type of dashboard are you planning to create - web-based or a graphical console app such as using [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)?